# Cannot send mail with no "From" header

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm getting this error help! i'm trying to send email but its not working

```
        $this->email->from('you@example.com', 'Your Name');
        $this->email->to($data['email']);
        $this->email->subject('This the test');
        $this->email->message('this is the test message');

        $this->email->send();

        if(! $this->email->send()){

            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }

        else
        {
            echo 'send';
        }
```

i'm getting this error

```
 Cannot send mail with no "From" header.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code you've already used `$this->email->send(`) before using again `$this->email->send()` in your if statement. The library, after you send an email, clears everything. So, if you want to do something in case of error you don't do the same method twice:

```
 $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->from('you@example.com', 'Your Name');
        $this->email->to($data['email']);
        $this->email->subject('This the test');
        $this->email->message('this is the test message');
// $this->email->send(); don't do this and then the same thing!

 if (!$this->email->send())
{    
echo $this->email->print_debugger();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that any initialize code e.g.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Is before you set from, to, subject etc.